# Fetch random objects from Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I need to fetch random objects from core data file, say 10 random objects.

How can i do that?

Here is my `NSFetchRequest` setup

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)fetchRandom
{
if (!_fetchRandom) {
    _fetchRandom = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
}
[_fetchRandom setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:self.oneManagedObjectContext]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"checked = %@", @"0"];
[_fetchRandom setPredicate:predicate];

NSUInteger count = [self.oneManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:_fetchRandom error:NULL];


NSUInteger random = (arc4random() % 5) + 3;

[_fetchRandom setFetchLimit:random];

return _fetchRandom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not fetching 10 random objects here . Instead by setting the fetch limit to random , you are fetching random number of objects.

For actually fetching random Objects you have to change your predicate.

One way to do that is assign a attribute to the entity with some number as its value - say "sortKey" , assign it uniquely to each object while constructing your database.

Now get 10 random values and change your predicate to return object with sortKey in this set of 10 random Values.

setFetchLimit to 10.